# How to test which tab is selected in VB.net TabControl

Tags: .net, vb.net, tabcontrol

I have a TabControl with two TabPages and I was wondering what is the best way to test which tab is currently displayed? I'm not sure why I can't figure this one out...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[TabControl.SelectedTab](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.selectedtab.aspx)

Answer (score 10):

```
Private Sub TabControl_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TabControl.SelectedIndexChanged
    If TabControl.SelectedTab Is tabMyTab Then
        ' do whatever...
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Worked for me to control the close form event!

Answer (score 9):

use that tab's "ENTER EVENT "
eg.

```
   Private Sub TabName_Enter(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TabName.Enter
        MsgBox("me the tab selected")
         'or do whattever u like
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

```
TabControl.SelectedTab.
```

Here's [the link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.selectedtab.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

If you use .Net 3.5, you can create a IsSelected method as an extension method if you wish:

```
Public Module TabControlExtensions
    <Extension()> _
    Public Function IsSelected(ByVal tabPage As TabPage) As Boolean
        Dim tabControl = CType(tabPage.Parent, TabControl)
        Return (tabControl.SelectedTab Is tabPage)
    End Function
End Module
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is a WPF application, make sure that each TabItem has an Name.

Then it's just a matter of checking.

```
if tabItem1.IsSelected = true then
  ' Do Something 
else if tabItem2.IsSelected = true then
  ' Do Something 
end if
```

Comment: Yeah, this is how I was figuring how to do it but there's no members called IsSelected or Selected, I guess you have to use SelectedTab, kinda ugly but it works.

Comment: doing a bit more lokoing into this, apparently the IsSelected is only available for the WPF TabItem class.  The WinForms one doesn't support the IsSelected property.

Answer (score 1):

Try This..

this is how to modify each of the tab when selected
then there will be a function of each tab

**First Grading |Second Grading |**

```
Private Sub TabControlAction(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles nameoftab.Click

        If nameoftab.SelectedTab.Text = "Second Grading" Then
            Msgbox("Second Grading is Selected")
''Place whatever your want

        Else
            Msgbox("First Grading is Selected")
''Place whatever your want
        End If

    End Sub
```

You can use if elseif else statement though.

this find works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the "TAG" propety for each individual tab using the TabPages collection editor.  Set each tag to a number representing the Tab sequence (starting at 1 or 0 or whatever to suit)

```
Private Sub TabControl1_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles TabControl1.Click

    Dim ActiveTabNumber as Integer = TabControl1.SelectedTab.Tag

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

```
TabControl1_Click:
    If TabControl1.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
        ' Do Something       
    ElseIf TabControl1.SelectedIndex = 1 Then
        ' Do Something 
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack overflow! Looks like a great answer and hopefully it solves the OPs problem nicely (I don't know, I'm not a VB programmer)... I just thought I should say that it's often best to expand on your answer and explain how/why it solves the problem. We get a lot of newbies - or people like me who are great at programming, but not in this language... and a bit of explanation can help us better understand your code snippet, and learn a thing from you.

Answer (score 1):

I have a TabControl called tcMode, with members/items called tcmRelease and tcmSwitch, and the following works nicely for me with the ability to move the tabs around/rename without worrying;

```
If tcMode.SelectedTab Is tcmRelease Then
      'Do Something if first tab selected
ElseIf tcMode.SelectedTab Is tcmSwitch Then
      'Do something if second tab selected
End If
```

[Image of Tab Control Members](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUDKR.png)

Answer (score 0):

Can also do the following:

```
Dim TabName As String

TabName = YourTabControl.SelectedTab.Name

If TabName.Contains("YourTabName") Then
    ' Do something
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will show the current selected tab name

```
 Private Sub Tab_new1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Tab_new1.SelectedIndexChanged
        MsgBox(Tab_new1.SelectedTab.Name)
    End Sub
```