# Why does my data does not display after changing tabs?

Tags: database, vb.net, datagridview, tabcontrol

I'm using a DataGrid with TabControl. When I move to the 2nd tab my data is not displaying in the datagridview. My 2nd IF statement is not getting executed, I'm not sure why either.  Only the 1st statement is being execute in selectedIndex 0. Please help me out.

```
Private Sub TabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TabControl1.SelectedIndexChanged
    If TabControl1.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
        MyCn.Open()
        MyDatAdp = New SqlDataAdapter("select * from Books", MyCn)
        MyCmdBld = New SqlCommandBuilder(MyDatAdp)
        MyDatAdp.Fill(MyDataTbl)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = MyDataTbl
        MyCn.Close()

        If TabControl1.SelectedIndex = 1 Then
            MyCn.Open()
            MyDatAdp = New SqlDataAdapter("select * from Orders", MyCn)
            MyCmdBld = New SqlCommandBuilder(MyDatAdp)
            MyDatAdp.Fill(MyDt2)
            DataGridView2.DataSource = MyDt2
            MyCn.Close()
        End If


    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: How could execution ever enter that second `If` block? You're checking whether the `SelectedIndex` is 1 but, if you're at that point, you already know for a fact that the `Selectedindex` is 0. Put a little more thought into how you structure that code.

Comment: Should I be using an Else If instead?

Comment: Try it, _Else If_ or _select case_ should work.

Comment: I just edited my code above, it still does not seem to work.

Comment: I think I found the problem, my SelectedIndex is always = 0. Should I be changing it to TabPages or something else?

Comment: Have you though about subscribing to the `SelectedIndexChanged` event instead? I.e., have you verified when the `TabIndexChanged` event is raised and what this event is related to?

Comment: @Jimi … didn’t even see that… As Jimi suggest, you probably want the tab controls `SelectedIndexChanged` event. The `TabIndexChanged` event fires when the tab controls `TabIndex` value changes. This is the tab order of the `TabControl` itself and has nothing to do with the user switching tab pages. Also, are you sure you want to “re-load” the data into the grid “every time” the user switches tabs? I would think loading the data into the grid(s) ONCE for each tab page would be a better approach.

Comment: @JohnG thanks to you, it's working now. Could you please help me on how to do this " I would think loading the data into the grid(s) ONCE for each tab page". I really have no idea

Comment: Move all the code that fills both combo boxes into the forms `Load` event.

Comment: That does not seem to work bc I'm using TabControl1.SelectedIndex to check

Comment: You state… _”That does not seem to work bc I'm using TabControl1.SelectedIndex to check”_ … ? …  Yes, it does work using the forms `Load` event. Using the `TabControl1.SelectedIndex` to check is irrelevant. What are you “checking” for anyway? Just fill the grids and that is it. Without seeing your changes, speculation is all you may get. [edit] your question and add your updated code.

Comment: I have multiple tabs. each tab displays different data. That's what I'm checking for.

Comment: _”I have multiple tabs. each tab displays different data. That's what I'm checking for.”_ … When the form `LOADS` and the forms `Load` event is called, the tab pages and grids have already been created. There is no need to “check” anything. Tab page 1 has the grid for X data, so fill that grid with X data. Tab page 2 has the grid for Y data, so fill that grid with Y data etc.…  I am just not following “what” you would be checking for when the form/tab pages are loaded with data.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the `If TabControl1.SelectedIndex` To `If TabControl1.SelectedTab is yourTabPage Then`

And see this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472083/how-to-test-which-tab-is-selected-in-vb-net-tabcontrol) for your reference.